# Script crawls only the first page instead of multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl multiple pages of a website. But the program can only crawl the first page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
import time

def make_soup(url):

    source = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    pattern = re.compile(r'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:(\{.*\})};')
    script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
    jsonData = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)

    pattern_number = re.compile(r'\"[0-9]{9,12}\":(\{\"data\":\{\"cachedFilters\":(.*?)\}\}),\"[0-9]{9,11}\"')
    jsonData2 = pattern_number.search(jsonData).group(1)

    dictData = json.loads(jsonData2)
    return dictData

def get_reviews(dictData):

    """ Return a list of five dicts with reviews.
    """

    all_dictionaries = []

    for data in dictData['data']['locations']:
        for reviews in data['reviewListPage']['reviews']:

            review_dict = {}

            review_dict["reviewid"] = reviews['id']
            review_dict["reviewurl"] =  reviews['absoluteUrl']
            review_dict["reviewlang"] = reviews['language']
            review_dict["reviewdate"] = reviews['createdDate']

            userProfile = reviews['userProfile']
            review_dict["author"] = userProfile['displayName']

            all_dictionaries.append(review_dict)

    return all_dictionaries

def main():

    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS'

    dictData = make_soup(url)
    review_list = get_reviews(dictData) # list with five dicts
    #print(review_list)

    page_number = 5

    while page_number <= 260: # number in the URL
        next_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-or' + str(page_number) + '-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS'
        dictData = make_soup(url)
        review_list2 = get_reviews(dictData)
        print(review_list2)

        page_number += 5
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I'm not sure if I can crawl multiple pages with this URL. On the website there are 54 pages, but in the URL I always have to add the number 5, like this:

```
Page 1
https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS

Page2
https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-or5-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS

Page3
https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-or10-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS
```

I don't know if this is a good idea. 
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean in the paragraph starting with _And I’m not sure if I can crawl...._

Comment: Sorry :-D Ok, lets say it like this: can I crawl multiple pages with this URL?

Comment: did you try it? As I know using `or5`, `or10`, etc. it should read pages. There was similar question long time ago and I probably used `or5`, `or10` in answer to read pages. Here is [this answer](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/tripadvisor.com%20-%20scrapy). Inside code you should find link to question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @furas thank you very much! Your code outputs exactly that what I need :-) First, I also tried to crawl this website with scrapy, but then for crawling ratings I had to change to json. Do you have idea why my code above is not working for multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assing new url to `next_url` but you use `url` to read page.

```
next_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-or' + str(page_number) + '-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS'
dictData = make_soup(url)
```

You have to rename variable

```
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-or' + str(page_number) + '-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS'
dictData = make_soup(url)
```

Comment: even I didn't see this mistake in first moment - I had to use `print(url)` inside `make_soup()` to see it.